# HammerJS Integration with Meteor and ReactJS

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs, hammer.js, meteor-react

I'm looking to add Hammer JS to my app built on Meteor with React. I am running into a problem when integrating different libraries.

Currently, I've tried a few different available libraries like:
https://github.com/JedWatson/react-hammerjs, but I receive this error:

[image]

I've also looked into: 
https://atmospherejs.com/chriswessels/hammer
but, it doesn't look like it supports ReactJS. If anyone can help point me in the right direction, or point to what they have done please let me know!

Answer (score 2):

You can add Hammer library to your web page and use it from React code.

**Linking**

I'm not sure about your project structure. I just downloaded the js file, put it in the public folder and added corresponding `<script>` tag before the one which points to js file with bundled React code.

**Usage**

As described [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/reactjs/9gYGpI1s_Mo) you can go with the following code:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
  this.hammer = Hammer(this.getDOMNode())
this.hammer.on('swipeleft', this.swipeLeft);
},
componentWillUnmount: function() {
this.hammer.off('swipeleft', this.swipeLeft);
```

}